# Is there any way to update QTY programmatically using front controller?

Tags: magento-2.1.2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

$productStockData = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId()); 

$productStockData->setData('is_in_stock', 0);

$productStockData->setData('qty', 0);

$productStockData->setData('manage_stock', 1);

$productStockData->save();

echo "<pre>";

print_r($productStockData->getData());

exit;

$product->save();
```

This code gives the result with correct qty in array print but not reflecting in database ..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more simple:

`$quantity = 10;
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $quantity, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);`

Of course don't use Object Manager directly - any needed classes and dependencies include in constructor of your controller - using automatic depenedency injection.

Moreover try to load product via `Product Repository`:`\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` (take a look at `di.xml` in `Magento_Catalog` and notice that many model classes used for similar operations can (and should be) loaded via their interfaces (you can find them in `Magento\Catalog\Api`).

Using repository you can use method `get` if you have `sku` of your product or `getById` if you have its `id`.

So it should all look like (more or less, not tested):

```
public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
... (other controller dependencies)
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function updateQuantity($id, $quantity)
    {
       //Load product
       $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
       //set values
       $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $quantity, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
       //save product with new values
       $this->productRepository->save($product);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but still not working :(

Comment: Sorry @lord_of_strings, It was my mistake. Your solution is working successfully but after remove cache from var folder it gives me correct output. so i think now caching is issue

Comment: In magento development first step to debug is clearing `cache`, `page_cache`, `generation`, `di`. Sometimes if it doesn't help try clearing `view_preprocessed` in `var`. In case of working with html and knockout it is essential to clear `pub/static` (be careful to not remove `.htaccess`.